# Routing HTTP response back through different server by perceiving origin server IP

Tags: http, nginx, networking, haproxy

I want to achieve following http/https traffic flow.

```
Client (not owned)
 ↓    ↑
 * Server 1  ←  ←  ←  ←  ←
  ↓              
  Server 2 (not owned)    ↑
   ↓          
   * Server 3 →  →  →  →  →
   ↓    ↑
   Target (not owned)

* I have control of servers marked with *
Server 2 is HTTP proxy server
```

1. **Client** sends HTTP/HTTPS request to **Target** using **Server 1** as HTTP proxy.
2. **Server 1** (which I have control of) receives request and change **Target** to **Server 3** and forwards request to **Server 3** using **Server 2** as a proxy. I do not have control of Server 2 and I can not configure it's software.
3. **Server 3** (which I have control of) receives the request and change target back to **Target**. However here **Server 3** MUST perceive IP of **Server 2** so **Target** see that request was send from **Server 2** IP.
4. **Target** (I don't have control of) sends response back to **Server 2** through **Server 3**. But here **Server 3** must route response back to **Server 1** without letting it through **Server 2**.

The goal is for requests to go through **Server 2** but responses go through different path. **Target** must see that request came from IP of **Server 2**.

How it all can be achieved? What softwares have to be used? If it's even possible?